# how to use modulo in this formula

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I Have this formula:
$$(n-1)!(\frac{n(n-1)}{2} + \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{4})$$
$2\le n\le 100000$.
I would like to modulate the result of this from this formula by any modulus, but for the moment let's assume that it is constant, `MOD = 999999997`. Unfortunately I can't just calculate the result and modulate it, because unfortunately I don't have variables larger than `2^64` at my disposal, so the main question is. What factors to modulate by MOD to get the results%MOD ?
Now let's assume that `n=19`. What is in brackets is equal to `247.5`

`18! = 6402373705728000`.
`(6402373705728000 * 247.5)mod999999997 = 921442488`.
Unfortunately, in case I modulate 18! first, the result will be wrong, because `(18!)mod999999997 = 724935119.    (724935119 * 247.5)mod9999997 = 421442490.`
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your second calculation $(724935119 * 247.5)\bmod 9999997 = 421442490\,$ is incorrect. The correct answer agrees with your first calcuation. Your calculator may be confused by the use of decimals in mod arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use floating point operations. Use integer values for your modulo operations. YOu can use decimal representation as long as your calculations are exact (nod rounding errrors) because the decimal fraction are equivalent to integer fractions.

Here the error is that $421442490$ is wrong because $$724935119 \cdot  247.5\pmod{9999997} \\
= 421442489.5\pmod{9999997}\\
=421442489+\frac 1 2\pmod{9999997}$$

But $\frac 1 2\pmod{9999997}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $2\pmod{9999997}$ which is $499999999$ because
$$2\cdot 499999999=1\pmod{9999997}$$
Therefore
$$421442489+\frac 1 2\pmod{9999997}\\
=421442489+499999999\pmod{9999997}\\
=921442488\pmod{9999997}$$
which is the expected result.

You can avoid decimal fractions by
either you making things complicate and by calculation $\frac 1 2 \pmod {999999997}$ and $\frac 1 4 \pmod {999999997}$, which are called the [modular multiplicative inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of $2$ and $4$ or by taking an appropriate factor from the $(n-1)!$-term and multiply it to the $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} + \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{4}$ term to avoid fractions.

$$(n-1)!(\frac{n(n-1)}{2} + \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{4})\\
=1\cdot2\cdot3 \cdot(5\cdot\ldots\cdot(n-1))\cdot4\cdot(\frac{n(n-1)}{2} + \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{4})\\
=6\cdot(5\cdot\ldots\cdot(n-1))(2n(n-1) + (n-1)(n-2))$$

Comment: Not true. Rational decimals make sense in mod arithmetic as long as the corresponding fraction exists, ie. if the lowest  term denominator is coprime to the modulus. But decimal notation is rarely used for modular fractions.

Comment: @BillDubuque I wrote floating point operations

Comment: The floating point operations will still work fine for modular arithmetic as long as one has enough precision (i.e. so that the float result is the correct rational result), and presuming the mod operation has the logic to deal with decimals and fractions (not all computer algebra systems implement such).

Comment: Worth mention: it is not clear if the multiplication will be a floating point product or a modular product. That depends on the computer algebra system.